# Ajustar orientação horizontal e vertical no Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Minha página na horizontal está da maneira que eu quero:

[image: pag na horiz]

Mas se deixar o celular vertical ela está ficando assim:

[image: pag na vert]

Como fazer para que na vertical fique da seguinte forma?

[image: layout desejado]

Segue meu código:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/btnHome.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/btnProduto.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/btnContato.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa mecher no css, só remover a classe col-xs-4 que é referente aos "Extra Small Devices", e assim as divs ficam em linhas e não em colunas nos dispositivos de largura menor que 768px. Vai aí o código editado:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/btnHome.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/btnProduto.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/btnContato.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tive uma dúvida vendo seu código.
O uso duas classes col (sm e md), ajuda a responsividade em telas de diferentes tamanhos?
Até então, eu só usava uma classe.

Agradeço se puder esclarecer essa minha dúvida.
Abs

Comment: @AngeloScali Sim, você pode alterar o tamanho das colunas da grade de acordo com a largura do dispositivo. A tabela de valores das larguras e respectivos prefixos você vê aqui: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score -2):

Coloque `float:left` nas duas últimas `divs`.

Comment: Coloquei e não adiantou Rafael..

Comment: não mudou nada?

Comment: Não, não mudou nada..

Comment: Consegui resolver usando media queries, segue oque fiz:

@media (min-width: 500px)
{
    .opcoesHome .row .col-md-4
    {
        width: 33.33333333%;
        float: left;
    }
}